# Calling variable from helper class

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to simplify my code by using a helper class to search users for a query. I have the following helper class:

```
public class RoleUtils {

    public static ID userId {get;set;} //variable for this user id
    public static ID userRoleId {get;set;} //variable for this user role id
    public static Set<ID> userSubs {get;set;} //variable for all subordinates to this user in role hierarchy
    public static Set<ID> userSubRoles {get;set;}
    public static Set<ID> userPar {get;set;} //variable for all parents to this user in role hierarchy
    public static Set<ID> usergroup {get;set;}

    public static void getIds(){
        usergroup = new Set<ID>();
        userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        usergroup.add(userId);
        userRoleId = UserInfo.getUserRoleId();
        userSubRoles = new Set<ID>();

        for(UserRole subRole :[select Id from UserRole where ParentRoleId = :userRoleId AND ParentRoleID != null])
        {
            userSubRoles.add(subRole.Id);
        }
        for(User subuser :[SELECT ID, UserRoleId FROM User WHERE UserRoleId IN :userSubRoles])
        {
            usergroup.add(subuser.Id);
        }


        system.debug('userId '+userId);
        system.debug('userRoleId '+userRoleId);
        system.debug('userSubRoles '+userSubRoles);
        system.debug('usergroup '+usergroup);
    }
}
```

I've tested this and it works fine.

In another class I have the following:

```
public void myDash(){
    Date currentDate = System.today();
    Date minusonemonth = currentDate.addMonths(-1);
    Date plusoneyear = currentDate.addYears(1);
    Date plusthreemonths = currentDate.addDays(90);
    RoleUtils.getIds();

    getCon = [SELECT RecordTypeId, Contract_Number__c, OwnerId, Annual_Contract_Volume__c, Owned_by_me__c, Account__c, Account__r.Name, Id, Name, Utility__c, Contract_Nom_Group__c, Supplier__c, Consultant__c, Contract_End_Date__c, Pro_forma_Annual_Margin__c
            FROM NG_Contract__c
            WHERE Contract_End_Date__c >= :minusonemonth
            AND Contract_End_Date__c <= :plusthreemonths
            AND Annual_Contract_Volume__c > 0
//          AND OwnerId IN :usergroup
            ORDER BY Contract_End_Date__c ASC
            LIMIT 10];
```

How do I call the usergroup variable from my helper class to modify my getCon query to search for records owned by a user in that set?

Comment: you can combine the two queries into one BTW.  `...WHERE UserRoleID IN (Select id from UserRole where ....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just reference it statically similar to what you did with `getIds()`:

```
AND OwnerId IN :RoleUtils.userGroup
```